# Excel doesn't create structured formula for all tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Structured formula case

I am facing 2 weird issues with Excel 2013. I have been mainly using the tables. Initially when I created the sheet and inserted tables and added formulas, they were all using structured references like `=Table_Resource_Rates[Hourly Rate]`. But then for some tables and table columns, I get the cell references instead even if I am referring to cell in the table. Example: `E10`

[image: Excel table example]

How can I ensure that I will always get structured references?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please only ask one question per post. Ask your #2 question in a new post. I have removed it from this post to avoid confusion and clutter. Also, have you verified the columns giving cell references are in the actual table (formatted as a table)? Can you give us an example of your table?

Comment: Ok! Thanks! I will post second question as a new query. I added a picture in query above for an example. I have used only tables starting with Insert as a New Table option.

Comment: when this change happens? Can you reproduce the issue?

Comment: You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, which will solve the problem.

Comment: Can anyone help me with this problem?